# MySQL: Select from one table, add value from another table if exists

Tags: mysql, join

Lets assume two tables:

```
STUDENTS:
id | name | faculty_id
```

and:

```
FACULTIES:
id | name
```

I am trying to query for students by `students.id` and also return `faculties.name` where `students.faculty_id = faculties.id`.

I used:

```
SELECT students.*, faculties.name FROM students 
JOIN faculties on students.faculty_id = faculties.id
WHERE students.id = ' ... ';
```

This works well, however there is a problem:

If, by some mistake, the student was assigned a non-existent `faculty_id` than he would never be found. I would like to write more 'flexible' query that would return `faculty.name` only if match is found, otherwise just leave it empty.

Also, the query has to have no memory intensive loops, since you could query by name, etc... which results in large number of matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left join will return all students that meet your criteria whether or not student.faculty_id is associated with a valid faculty.id... the ifnull sets the value to blank if rather than "null"

```
    SELECT 
        students.*, 
        ifnull(faculties.name,'')
    FROM 
        students 
        LEFT JOIN faculties on students.faculty_id = faculties.id
    WHERE students.id = ' ... ';
```